# Use a PC PSU for powering a Raspberry Pi cluster and number of 5V+ cables

Tags: power-supply, atx

I need to power a cluster of 8 Raspberry Pis 4 and I have a 480W PC PSU with a maximum load of 28A on 5V+. My question is really simple and dumb (sorry for that) but I did not found a precise answer, but when I attach them to the 24pin motherboard connector should I use all the five 5V+ cables and 5 ground respectively? PSU cables are 20awg, and I estimated 3A for the Raspberry Pis so a total of 24A.

Comment: Can you provide more detail. Are the RPis plugged into a single motherboard (if so what is the model/manufacturer, do they have any recommendations for connecting power? Is there a power bus on the motherboard or is each RPi plugged into power independently? Clearly you can't run 28A through a power cable rated for 3A for an individual RPi. What do you mean by 5V+?

Comment: There's no a motherboard, I have a PC PSU with the following maximum loads https://i.imgur.com/2rYMDrE.jpg and I want to power 8 Raspberry Pi 4 without having 8 adapters and to put everything in a PC case. So I am picking five 5V+ wires from the 24pin atx cable https://i.imgur.com/kF52Bv1.jpg and two from the two molex lines of the PSU, and also 8 GND wires from the 24pin atx cable and other two GND wires from the two molex lines. That's the maximum number of cables that I can pick from the PSU, so they should be able to carry 28A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use all the 5V conductors and at least as many GND to reduce voltage drop over the cable; using extra grounds would only help.   With 5 supply and 5 return wires, each conductor will be carrying almost 5A.  Even this starts to push the limit of what you would want going over 20AWG.

Comment: @gabrielepmattia If you will use this PSU **only** for RPi's cluster, you could open the PSU, disconnect (cut or unsolder) all the other cables, and even replace the bunch of 5V conductors with a single thick conductor. Or connect the RPi's USB-C cables directly to the PSUs PCB.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your remark you are clearly right but I wanted the PSU to be replaceable without any further soldering, so I am using a 24pin ATX extension cable https://i.imgur.com/Vs3WDwx.jpg to pick the five 5V+ wires, and 8 GND wires. The female can be easily attached to the PSU and the male to a simple switch like this https://i.imgur.com/CCEKI4B.jpg I also pick other two 5V+ and GND wires from the two MOLEX lines of the PSU, for a total of 7 5V+ wires and 10 GND wires